# Less if statements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So, basically I want to make this function without that many If statements

currentFeatures are being set by the slider in another file.
cost is added if currentFeatures != previousFeatures, and if user changes it back and currentFeatures equals previousFeatures amount previously added to cost reverts

using: reactsjs, typescript

```js
   const [previousCustomization, setPreviousCustomization] =
   useState<HairFeatures>({
      hairstyle: '0',
      haircolor: '0',
      secondaryhaircolor: '0',
      hairtatoo: '0',
      facialhair: '0',
      facialhaircolor: '0',
      eyebrows: '0',
      eyebrowscolor: '0',
    });

  const [customization, setCustomization] = useState<HairFeatures>({
    hairstyle: '0',
    haircolor: '0',
    secondaryhaircolor: '0',
    hairtatoo: '0',
    facialhair: '0',
    facialhaircolor: '0',
    eyebrows: '0',
    eyebrowscolor: '0',
  });

  const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);

  const calculatePrice = (
    currentFeatures: HairFeatures,
    previousFeatures: HairFeatures
  ) => {
    let cost = 0;
    if (currentFeatures.hairstyle != previousFeatures.hairstyle) {
      cost += 50;
    }
    if (currentFeatures.hairtatoo != previousFeatures.hairtatoo) {
      cost += 20;
    }
    if (currentFeatures.haircolor != previousFeatures.haircolor) {
      cost += 120;
    }
    if (
      currentFeatures.secondaryhaircolor != previousFeatures.secondaryhaircolor
    ) {
      cost += 80;
    }
    if (currentFeatures.facialhair != previousFeatures.facialhair) {
      cost += 75;
    }
    if (currentFeatures.facialhaircolor != previousFeatures.facialhaircolor) {
      cost += 100;
    }
    if (currentFeatures.eyebrows != previousFeatures.eyebrows) {
      cost += 50;
    }
    if (currentFeatures.eyebrowscolor != previousFeatures.eyebrowscolor) {
      cost += 50;
    }
    setPrice(cost);
  };
```

fucnction that executes calculateprice() in other file

```js
const handleBuyButtonClick = () => {
    calculatePrice(customization, previousCustomization);
    console.log(price);
  };
```

Comment: Please consider providing a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE.  So, for example, you should provide a definition of `HairFeatures` and `handlePrice()`, or you should remove them from your code so that we don't need a definition for them.  If you can provide this then it's easier for others to get to work on the question without having to first spend time setting it up.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz thanks, i edited it and provided more information

Answer (score 3):

You can move the prices to a separate object and calculate the total price using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on that object's entries.

Create the costs object:

```
const costs: Record<keyof HairFeatures, number> = {
  hairstyle: 50,
  hairtatoo: 20,
  haircolor: 120,
  secondaryhaircolor: 80,
  facialhair: 75,
  facialhaircolor: 100,
  eyebrows: 50,
  eyebrowscolor: 50,
};
```

And use reduce on it's entries to calculate the total cost:

```
const cost = Object.entries(costs).reduce((acc, [feature, price]) => {
  return acc + (currentFeatures[feature] !== previousFeatures[feature] ? price : 0);
}, 0);
```

Comment: round braces after + and in the end of line are required in this case

Comment: Oh, sorry! You're right, didn't notice on SO's editor

Comment: i edited my post and provided more informations, also im using reactjs and typescript

Comment: @deBBuu you can replace your `calculatePrice` function content with the code i've provided, add the `setPrice(cost);` at the end and there should be no problem.